# how to parse previously fetch whois data with Ruby Whois?

Tags: ruby, parsing, whois, whois-ruby

According to README on github, Ruby Whois can be used *"as a standalone library to parse WHOIS records fetched previously and/or from different WHOIS clients."*

I know how to use the library to directly perform whois query and parse the returning result. But **I cannot find anywhere(stackoverflow included) how I can use this library to parse whois data previously fetched ?**

I think it's not important but this is how I get my data, anyway: they are fetched through linux whois command and stored in separate files, each file containing one whois query result.

The manual pages on https://whoisrb.org/ are 404. Even the code on the homepage is outdated thus wrong, and the doc pages provide little information.

I tried to scan the source code on **github**( https://github.com/weppos/whois-parser and https://github.com/weppos/whois). I tried to find the answer on **rubydoc** ( https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/whois-parser/Whois/Parser, https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/whois/Whois/Record and some related pages). Both failed, partly because this task is the first time and the reason that I use Ruby.

So could anyone help me? I'm really desperate and I'll definitely appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
require 'whois-parser'

domain = 'google.com'
data = 'WHOIS DATA THAT YOU ALREADY HAVE'

whois_server = Whois::Server.guess domain
whois_data = [Whois::Record::Part.new(body: data, host: whois_server.host)]
record = Whois::Record.new(whois_server, whois_data)

parser = record.parser
parser.available? #=> false
parser.registered? #=> true
```